# Magento 2 - Changing "enter coupon here" to "Enter coupon or voucher here"

Tags: magento2, template

I'd like to change placeholder on the coupon field from "enter coupon here" to "enter coupon or voucher here". I've enabled template hints but couldn't find out what template it's pulling from.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use translations:

1. In your theme create `app/design/frontend/Package/Theme/i18n/en_US.csv` replacing `en_US` with the locale of your choice
2. Add `"enter coupon here":"Enter coupon or voucher here"` to this file

If it doesn't work:

- Ensure you have cleared all caches
- Ensure the text matches exactly (translations are case sensitive)